# Fix text position in rasterVis::vectorplot

Tags: r, plot, raster, rastervis

I'm trying to fix the position of some text in a `rasterVis::vectorplot` so that it stays in the same position even if I change the width and height of the png file.

I tried using the margin parameters of `par` but with no luck.

This is an example of what I got so far:

```r
#Some raster data
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-2, 2, .01), y = seq(-2, 2, .01))
    
df$z <- with(df, (3*x^2 + y)*exp(-x^2-y^2))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=proj)
        
#[A]
png("test01.png",width = 918,height = 850,res=100)
vectorplot(r,par.settings=list(layout.widths = list(axis.key.padding = 3)),
           narrows = 500,length=0.1,lwd.arrows=0.4)
grid.text(substr(R.version.string, 1, 15),rot=90, x=0.92,y=0.14,gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface = "italic"))
dev.off()
```

This is the output of [A]. That's how I want it:

[image: 1]

Now, changing the width and height:

```r
##[B]
png("test02.png",width = 1718,height = 850,res=100)
vectorplot(r, 
           par.settings=list(layout.widths = list(axis.key.padding = 3)),
           narrows = 500,length=0.1,lwd.arrows=0.4)
grid.text(substr(R.version.string, 1, 15),rot=90, x=0.92,y=0.14,gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface = "italic"))
dev.off()
```

This is the output of [B]:

[image: 2]

As you can see the text doesn't stay in the same place. (I'm new with the rasterVis library.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`layer` function](https://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#layer) of the `latticeExtra` package with `panel.text` will help you here. The `panel.text` functions prints inside the area of the panel, so you have to add the option `clip = list(panel = FALSE)` to the settings list in order to print outside this area:

```
library(grid)
library(rasterVis)

vectorplot(r,par.settings=list(clip = list(panel = FALSE),
                               layout.widths = list(axis.key.padding = 3)),
           narrows = 500,length=0.1,lwd.arrows=0.4) +
    layer(panel.text(2.05, -2,
                     substr(R.version.string, 1, 15),
                     adj = c(0, 1),
                     srt = 90))
```

[image]